# nano change line numbers color

Tags: configuration, theme, nano

How can I change the actual editor theme in .nanorc, I am not speaking about the syntax highlighting but editor elements such as titlebar or line numbers color/background color?

For instance, I would like to set the title bar and line numbers background to black/transparent, and the font color to white.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `nanorc` file, and add the following lines:

```
set titlecolor COLOR_1,COLOR_2    # COLOR_1 is the text, COLOR_2 is the background. Supported colors are white, black, blue, green, red, cyan, yellow, magenta
set numbercolor COLOR_1,COLOR_2   # same as above
```

Comment: Nice! Does the trick thanks. Would you happen to know how to get the "device theme colors"? By default, my "white" seems to be blue-ish. But when I set white in the config, it is regular white (or actually grey.) and the unset white (line numbers background/commands help) appears like the default device blueish white color. see here: https://i.imgur.com/eI2Snwj.png

Comment: That's odd... mine looks like [this](https://i.ibb.co/HKz2gXH/Screenshot-from-2022-08-28-15-47-14.png). I'm not sure why, but it might be the terminal, the terminal's theme or something similar. AFAIK, it's not possible to set color codes or anything in `nano` - just the colors I mentioned. Have you tried changing your terminal's theme or tried to open `nano` with a different terminal emulator?

Comment: You're right, I actually checked "Use color from system theme" in Terminator but I had to overwrite the color palette too for it to work everywhere!